# Why is the size of an empty queue reduced by one after pop?

Tags: c++, queue

```
#include <queue>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    std::queue<int> q;
    printf("%d\n", q.size());

    q.pop();
    q.pop();

    printf("%d\n", q.size());  // ===> prints -2

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably because popping an empty container invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: If you fix the bug in your program everything will go back to making sense. (IOW "why is it that my buggy program doesn't behave properly?" is a poor question)

Comment: ..and -1 return is a good clue that the method is complaining about it.

Comment: Also, it's not printing -1 it's printing max value of the size_t data type, which when improperly converted in "%d" is outputted as -1.  YOu should start using <iostream> and cout instead.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `queue.pop()` on an empty container yields undefined behavior, so you cannot really rely on anything about your program after you've done this.

Having your queue potentially damaged and report a size() of -1 is correct/good/bad as anything when you've invoked undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

It is undefined behaviour to pop from an empty queue.

Undefined behavoir can include many things such as formatting your harddrive (unlikely!), making demons appear from your nose (also unlikely) or sometimes doing exactly what you expect (likely and very worrying)

You're also printing a size_t using `%d` which will only lead to trouble. Try using `%zu` (on gcc/clang) or `%Iu` on Visual Studio

Answer (score 2):

According to [Unexpected behavior from STL's queue](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55841) with a little tweak.

> std::queue is a very thin adaptor (i.e. wrapper) around another container, the behaviour you are reporting is actually the behaviour of std::deque, not std::queue since you don't change the default container.
>
> **calling pop() on an empty sequence** is **undefined behaviour.**